# User input validation in managed bean problem(JSF 2.0 )

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I am having some problems when i try to validate the user input from my JSF, in a managed beans. I recive the validation message in the console, but i dont see it in the page. I dont understand where is the problem.

This is the console output:

> INFO: Inside validation method!!
>   INFO: NO MATCH!!!
>   INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver. 
>   INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
>   sourceId=bRegForm:name[severity=(INFO 0), summary=(Your name cannot contain special characters), detail=(Your name cannot contain special characters)]

This is how i made the JSF input component:

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{registrationController.name}" validator="#{registrationController.validateName}" required="true">
        <h:message for="name"/>
    </h:inputText>
```

And this is how how i created the validation method:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class RegistrationController {
...
public void validateName(FacesContext context, UIComponent validate,
        Object value) {
    String inputFromField = (String) value;
    String simpleTextPatternText = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$";
    Pattern textPattern = null;
    Matcher nameMatcher = null;
    textPattern = Pattern.compile(simpleTextPatternText);
    nameMatcher = textPattern.matcher(inputFromField);
    System.out.println("Inside validation method!!");
    if (!nameMatcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH!!!");
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                Your name cannot contain special characters);
        throw new ValidatorException(msg);
    }
}
```

As you see i manage to get inside the validation method when i try inputs that do contain special characters like: G#^r$>',... and i see the message that advice about it in the console, but i dont see the message on the displayed on the page, next to the input field.
By the way: I also noticed that when i give empty input i dont see any validation messages and i did make it required="true".
I checked the Error Log and also the console, but i dont find any Exceptions that can give me clues(Just the WARNING message that i copy pasted above).
I am a begginer with JSF 2.0 It is the third day i am stuck with this problem, i dont know to solve it. Do i need to configure any XML? Do i need to implement any interface? Override any method?... Ill be very happy if someone could have a look at it and give me a hand. In advance thank you very much for your time reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<h:message>` should not be nested inside `<h:inputText>`. Put them next to each other.

Comment: BalusC friend, thank you very much. I finally fixed the problem :) That was it the for attribute takes care of linking the component to the message. So in my case the message had no need to be nested. I also notice that eclipse now displays a little envelope next to that field to advice that it has a validation message.  Finally :) tnx again.